# How can I identify a good beer garden in Munich (Germany)?

Tags: food-and-drink, alcohol, munich, tourist-traps

I am planning to visit Munich soon and the most consistent piece of advice I have gotten is that I have to visit some beer gardens while I am there. However, I have been warned that, other than the Hofbrauhaus, I should not go where the tourists go. Apparently, going to a bad, "tourist trappy" location will ruin my day faster than going to a good one will improve it.

My knowledge of German is limited to "hello" and "thank you." I do not look like a native. I don't know much about German culture. What signs can I look for to determine whether a particular beer garden is a good one or a tourist trap? Or, more generally, if I am not standing outside a beer garden, how can I find a good one?

Comment: My advise would be to not worry about it too much, drinking beer in Munich is a well worn path where ever you go, just drink and enoy yourself.

Comment: Wait a minute! Do you mean non-German tourists?  German tourists from all over  flood Bavaria in the summer and fall. If you are looking for 'authenticity', take the 2 hour train ride to Deggendorf.

Comment: I am disappointed in this closure. I am not asking "hai guys what's your favorite beer haha." I am asking how to identify tourist traps, but for a specific type of establishment. A useful, concrete travel skill, not an opinion.

Comment: @Dan we all find enjoyment in different ways. In my case, a quite large part of it is making sure I'm at a proper location first, hence the need for this question.

Comment: @GayotFow I actually do not know. Not sure if non-German tourists would be catered to differently than German tourists. Authenticity was not the sole motivator for this question, but regardless, thank you for the tip, I will look up Deggendorf.